# setInterval function call only once in program

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to make simplest image slide, which scroll image in div from left to right.

my issue is setInterval function runs only once and I am struggling of why or how to fix.

Many thanks in advance. I am calling setInterval function jQuery document.ready(function..

```
<div class="highlight_Block" id="FeaturesList_block">
   <div id="img_wrapper_05">
      <ul id="FeaturesList_Ul">

       <li id="DEMO1_000001" class="FeaturesList_li">
          <img src="http://www.hostpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract-color-349935.jpg" height="214" width="321">
       </li>

       <li id="DEMO1_000002" class="FeaturesList_li">
          <img src="http://www.hostpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Abstract-06-HD-wallpaper.jpg" width="321">
       </li>

       <li id="DEMO1_000003" class="FeaturesList_li">
          <img src="http://www.hostpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/abstract-wallpapers-wallpaper-array-wallwuzz-hd-wallpaper-2830.jpg" height="214" width="321">
       </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
setInterval(function () {
  var xyPosition_05 = $("#img_wrapper_05").position();
  var next_X_Position = xyPosition_05.left + 321;
  next_X_Position = '-' + next_X_Position + 'px'
  $("#img_wrapper_05").animate({ left: next_X_Position }, 1000);
},5000);
```

CSS:

```
  .highlight_Block {
   float:left;
   width:321px;
   height:300px;
   margin-left:15px;
   margin-top:15px;
   background-color:aliceblue;

  }

  #FeaturesList_Ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
 }


.FeaturesList_li{
 display:inline-block;
 }


 #img_wrapper_05 {
 width:auto;
 height:214px;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:green;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. You may find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136261/how-to-make-a-setinterval-stop-after-some-time-or-after-a-number-of-actions)

Answer (score 5):

in the second iteration the left value get two `--`

```
setInterval(function () {
    var xyPosition_05 = $("#img_wrapper_05").position();

    var next_X_Position = xyPosition_05.left + 321;

    next_X_Position = (next_X_Position<0? next_X_Position : -next_X_Position) + 'px'


    $("#img_wrapper_05").animate({ left: next_X_Position }, 1000);

},5000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DaGTz/)

Comment: But do assign the return value of `setInterval` to some variable you can keep in scope. If ever you need to stop the animation, you'll want the interval id

Answer (score 0):

After animation just set div to its default position using following code:

```
 $("#img_wrapper_05").css('property','value');
```

thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to believe that the setInterval is not working. If your images are not sliding, it may be because of the wrong CSS.

Step 1: Add an alert to see if it is entering into the setInterval function.

```
alert("setInterval Entered");
```

Step 2: If you are getting the alerts every 5 seconds, it's not a javascript issue. Try this

```
var next_X_Position = xyPosition_05.left - 321;
next_X_Position = next_X_Position + 'px';
```

After first try, the value of left property is already negative.