# Stop a function on Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm a beginner on JS. I want to write a function that make body alternate the background color between red and white for about 5 seconds. I've written this code:

```
var x = 1;

function alarma() {
    setInterval(cambio, 200);

    function cambio() {
        if (x == 1) {
            $("body").css("background-color", "red");
            x = 2;
        }
        else {
            $("body").css("background-color", "white");
            x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I test the code and it worked, but I don't know how to do to execute the function only for 5 seconds.

Any idea about how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `setInterval` starts an interval. Did you try using `clearInterval`?

Comment: If I was trying to acheive this effect, I would instead use a CSS animation to alternate colours, apply it, and then remove it after five seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a setInterval stop after some time or after a number of actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136261/how-to-make-a-setinterval-stop-after-some-time-or-after-a-number-of-actions)

Comment: I'm a beginner, so the above question isn't too clear for me. Instead, the Nick solution's was what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, which assigns your interval into an `interval` variable and then uses `setTimeout` to clear that interval after 5 seconds.

```js
function alarma() {
  const interval = setInterval(cambio, 200);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, 5000);
  
  let x = 1;
  
  function cambio() {
    if (x == 1) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "red");
      x = 2;
    } else {
      $("body").css("background-color", "white");
      x = 1;
    }
  }
}

alarma();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```